# Describing an 'easy' rule in optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

I have a simple scenario where I have a Planning Entity holding an Integer problem fact like

```
[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9].
```

My goal is to use optaplanner to sort the list, divide it into sublists that contain all adjacent numbers, and calculate the average of each sublist.

For example, `[12][1][4][5][6][7][11][9][10]` should be divided into three sublists:

`[1]`,
`[4][5][6][7]` and
`[9][10][11][12]`

which have averages of
1,
5.5, and
10.5, respectively.

The overall score should be the sum of the averages, which is 17.

Some years ago, I could write this rule in Drools, which wasn't that easy but possible. But now, I want to switch to the modern calculation way with Constraint Streams.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to use OptaPlanner for this. Where is the optimization problem here?

Comment: @LukášPetrovický It's just a first thought for a use case. Later I want to add more rules like penalize if an integer = 42 is included etc. I just want to know if such a rule is technically possible or not.

Comment: Almost anything is technically possible. In this case, it'd be very hard, probably requiring an implementation of a custom constraint collector. (The experimental package in examples has one that could do it.) Practically, unless you have an actual optimization problem to solve, I wouldn't think about using a constraint solver.

Comment: @LukášPetrovický thanks a lot. Can you tell me if there is a website that explains how a custom constraint works or is there an example that i can download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you revert the model?

1. Model a fact Group (think the id that will get `[4][5][6][7]`, an planning entity Assignment (think `[4]`) with a planning variable group.
2. from(Assignment.class).groupBy(Assignment::getGroup, average(Assignment::getWeight)).penalize(...)

The only problem with this (besides that average() does not exist) is that average() returns a double (floating point numbers are not associative). You'll need it to return a BigDecimal and work with BigDecimal...Score.

Also, you'll want to active pillar swap moves to get better results faster.

Comment: `average()` does actually exist. :-) There is an overload that returns a `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I really appreciate your help. So my PlanningEntity currently looks like this: 

```@PlanningEntity
@Entity
public class Assignment {

     @PlanningId
     @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

     @PlanningVariable
     @ManyToOne
    private Integer nr;

    // No-arg constructor required for Hibernate and OptaPlanner
    public Assignment() {
    }

     @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + id + ")";
    }
.....
.....
```
I would be happy if you could give me suggestions that I can easily understand and try out.